# Adding a second 'action' to function for different div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following working code which fades in/out a div/button

js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

var offset = 150,

// duration of the animation (in ms)
scroll_top_duration = 3000,

// bind with the button link
$animation = $('.fade-in');

// display or hide the button
$(window).scroll(function(){
    ( $(this).scrollTop() > offset ) ? $animation.addClass('btn-visible') :
    $animation.removeClass('btn-visible');
});

});
```

html

```
<div id='top-btn'>
   <a class="fade-in" href="#">...</a>
</div>
```

I want to add/remove the same class (.btn-visible) to a different div in the opposite order, but can't seem to get it to work.

the other div is `<div id="btn2">...</div>`

I want it to addClass('btn-visible') when the .fade-in is removed

Comment: `$(this).scrollTop() <= offset ) ? $('#btn2').addClass('btn-visible') : $('#btn2').removeClass('btn-visible');`

Comment: Where does that line go in my code, right after inside the same block?

Comment: Just after the existing one.

Comment: Doing that removes the functionality of the previous button (and doesn't seem to add it to the other)

Comment: Create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), without which it will not be possible to see where is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not use both action in the if block;

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if( $(this).scrollTop() > offset ) {
       $animation.addClass('btn-visible');
       $('#btn2').removeClass('btn-visible'); 
    }
    else
    {
        $animation.removeClass('btn-visible');
        $('#btn2').addClass('btn-visible');
    }
});
```